# SQL: Query to set value based on group parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell, active-directory

I need help writing a query to do the following on a table in my DB:

```
Select all rows where the values in Column1 are the same
    If a 'Primary' has not been set in Column2 for any of them
        Set Column2 = 'Primary' for first row in the group 
    Else go on to the next group
```

Key points: I can only have one 'Primary' tag per group

Sample input:

```
Column1 | Column2 | 
ID1                 
ID1                       
ID1                     
ID2       Primary
ID2       
ID3       
ID3
```

Sample Result:

```
Column1 | Column2 | 
ID1       Primary         
ID1                       
ID1                     
ID2       Primary
ID2       
ID3       Primary   
ID3
```

Thank you!

Comment: How to find the first row of each group

Comment: Can you also help me with a query to find when there is more than 1 'Primary' for a group set?
This so that I can validate all of my data incase of other mistakes somewhere.

Comment: can you ask that as a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022723/sql-find-duplicated-values-associated-with-one-id    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMER` window function to find the first record per group then update only the records which doesnot have `primary` value in `column2`

Since there is no column available to find the first record per group i have used `(select null)` in `order by`

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #ee(Column1 VARCHAR(50),Column2 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #ee
VALUES ('ID1',NULL),
       ('ID1',NULL),
       ('ID1',NULL),
       ('ID2','Primary'),
       ('ID2',NULL),
       ('ID3',NULL),
       ('ID3',NULL)
```

**Update query:**

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY column1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
         FROM   #ee a
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   #ee b
                            WHERE  a.Column1 = b.Column1
                                   AND b.Column2 = 'primary'))
UPDATE cte
SET    Column2 = 'primary'
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**Result:**

```
Column1 Column2
------- -------
ID1     primary
ID1     NULL
ID1     NULL
ID2     Primary
ID2     NULL
ID3     primary
ID3     NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Column1  
     ,CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY [TargetColumn]) = 1 
          THEN  'Primary' 
          ELSE '' 
     END AS Column2
FROM TableName
```

`TargetColumn` will be the column that will decide in each group of Column1 which Value is the Primary Value.